# Removing rows with non-unique values across the columns in Pandas

Tags: pandas, duplicates

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
| id   | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
|------|------|------|------|------|
| 1    | A    | B    | C    | 0    |
| 2    | M    | 0    | M    | 0    |
| 3    | B    | B    | 0    | B    |
| 4    | X    | 0    | Y    | 0    |
```

I'd like to disregard any rows that have only one unique value across their respective columns. I'd end up with this:

```
| id   | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
|------|------|------|------|------|
| 1    | A    | B    | C    | 0    |
| 4    | X    | 0    | Y    | 0    |
```

This is a seemingly simple thing to do. But I can't seem to find any hints on how to do this in Pandas, since people seem most interested in removing rows that are duplicates of other rows, as opposed to those having nothing but duplicate values within the rows themselves.

```
df = [    {'id' : 1, 'col1' : 'A', 'col2': 'B', 'col3':   'C', 'col4':'0'},
          {'id' : 2, 'col1' : 'M', 'col2':   '0', 'col3': 'M', 'col4':'0'},
          {'id' : 3, 'col1' : 'B', 'col2':  'B', 'col3':  '0', 'col4':'0'},
          {'id' : 4, 'col1' : 'X', 'col2':  '0', 'col3':  'Y', 'col4':'0'}
          ]
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df = df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']]
df
```

Small note:  the value `'0'` is actually a string in my case.
And all rows have at least one value at this point.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
df[df.apply(lambda x: x[x != '0'].nunique(), axis=1) > 1]
```

[image]

---

With `'id'`

```
df.set_index('id')[df.set_index('id').apply(lambda x: x[x != '0'].nunique(), axis=1) > 1].reset_index()
```

[image]

Comment: please forgive me -- I made a mistake in the question! There is actually a first column, with an `id`. Ugh. I feel terrible. (and the column is numeric)

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck that is close to an unforgivable sin I think

Comment: I know!! I'm wasting other people's time (who are smarter than myself)!

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to look at your dataframe transposed and search for duplicates.

You can do something like this:

```
df.T.duplicated().any().T
```

That will give you the boolean series where rows have duplicates and filter your dataframe with this series.

Comment: um, I hate to admit this..but I made an omission on the question originally. I forgot to show that I do indeed have a `id` column...which is numeric.... I'm sorry!!

Comment: Use the usual set_index reset_index pattern to isolate your id column and set it back in the dataframe